# Change default Drop down value to current year

Tags: powerbi

I have a date drop down list that has 2019 and current year, the default select is ALL, I would like the ALL to change to Current so the user doesn't have to click on the drop down every time. is there a way to do it ?

Comment: Try selecting current year in the slicer and then saving it. Hopefully that works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't set a default and switch slicers, what you can do is use [Bookmarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-bookmarks). So you create one bookmark with the Default filter(s), then the other without it. You can then add the bookmarks to a button that you can click on and switch between the two. You can also set visuals to show and hide in a bookmark, so for example hide the data slicer in the 'default' view and when you click on the 'date range' the slicer will appear.

Hope that helps point you in the right direction

Comment: I created a new bookmark with the saved filter and that fixed it to have a default value. thx !